# Как составить регулярное выражение python?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет. Возникла такая проблема: нужна достать из строки текст, который находится между `'` и `(`.
Например, `' привет как дела (`. Нужно получить строку "привет как дела".

Comment: Используйте `re.search(r"'([^'(]+)\(", s).group(1)` / `re.findall(r"'([^'(]+)\(", s)`. Если надо, пробелы удаляйте с помощью `strip`. Ленивые квантиыфикаторы только усложняют задачу движку.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, можно задать вам вопрос как эксперту по RegEx'ам? Что посоветуете почитать об оптимизации и написании __эффективных__ RegEx'ов?

Comment: @MaxU: Хороший вопрос, но я не знаю правильного ответа. В сети много источников. Конечно, [Джефри Фридла](ftp://ftp.micronet-rostov.ru/linux-support/books/programming/Regexp/[O%60Reilly]%20-%20%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F,%203-%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B4.%20-%20[%D0%94%D0%B6.%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BB].pdf) нужно почитать, раздел "Построение эффективных
регулярных выражений". Главное - понимать, как работает парсер регулярных выражений в каждом конкретном случае.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [17]: s
Out[17]: "'aaa' привет как дела (bbb) 'second' blah-blah (XXX)"

In [18]: re.search(r"'([^']*?)\(", s).group(1)
Out[18]: ' привет как дела '

In [19]: re.findall(r"\'([^\']*?)\(", s)
Out[19]: [' привет как дела ', ' blah-blah ']
```

вариант удаляющий обрамляющие пробелы:

```
In [20]: re.search(r"'\s*([^']*?)\s*\(", s).group(1)
Out[20]: 'привет как дела'

In [21]: re.findall(r"\'\s*([^\']*?)\s*\(", s)
Out[21]: ['привет как дела', 'blah-blah']
```

PS более правильный вариант (для `re.search()`), кот. проверяет наличие найденной RegEx группы:

```
In [22]: m = re.search(r"'([^']*?)\(", s)

In [23]: if m:
    ...:     print(m.group(1))
    ...:
 привет как дела
```

Пример такого случая:

```
In [25]: re.search(r'(AAA)', 'xxxxxx').group(1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-788705b32c0d> in <module>()
----> 1 re.search(r'(AAA)', 'xxxxxx').group(1)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: @bytesmite, всегда пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 3):

Пример регулярки для поиска выражения между `'` и `(`:

```
import re

text = "...' привет как дела (..."
match = re.search(r"'(.+?)\(", text)

print(match.group(1))
# ' привет как дела '

print(match.group(1).strip())
# 'привет как дела'
```